# Cannot build Spark in IntelliJ 14

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, apache-spark

I setup Spark project (github master branch) in IntelliJ by following the steps given in [Spark Wiki here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-IntelliJ).

By default, the profiles enabled are maven-3 and scala-2.10.

Since i was facing the error `value q is not a member of StringContext`, I added:

```
"Additional Compiler Options"-Xplugin:/home/test/.m2/repository/org/scalamacros/paradise_2.10.4/2.0.1/paradise_2.10.4-2.0.1.jar"
```

When I tried to rebuild the project, I am getting the following error (which is as reported in the mailing list [here](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Spark-development-with-IntelliJ-tp10032p10163.html)):

```
Error:(169, 38) not found: value HiveShim 
...
Error:(255, 18) not found: type HiveFunctionWrapper 
...
/home/test/workspace/spark_source/spark->1.2.0/sql/hive/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/hive/parquet/FakeParquetSerD>e.scala Warning:(34, 2) @deprecated now takes two arguments; see the scaladoc. @deprecated("No code should depend on FakeParquetHiveSerDe as it is only intended as a " +
```

I have not enabled the hive profile, but still getting the error above.

Can anybody please give a step by step instruction (other than those given in [spark wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/SPARK/Contributing+to+Spark#ContributingtoSpark-IntelliJ)) to build Spark and run the examples from IntelliJ IDE?

Comment: Intellij support for spark is a hit and miss thing: I recall having seen those issues with spark 1.2 and 1.3. Each new version typically has new types of breakages - and also new fixes. Over the long haul (years) it is improving. Since Spark 1.5 usually the intellij build actually "just works".

Answer (score 0):

By following the wiki page, you have almost done all steps in IntelliJ IDE Setup.

For "HiveShim not found" issue, this file was used by spark-hive and sql/hive-thriftserver.
You could try to:
     1, click "generate sources and update folders for all projects" in IntelliJ maven project tab;
     2, click on spark-hive under "packages" in the left pane, then go to "Open Module Settings" - then explicitly add the v0.12.0/src/main/scala
folder to the sources by navigating to it and then +click to add
it as a source.